# Typescript - Allowed values for a property

Tags: typescript

What it the best way in Typescript to only allow a number of value for a property ?

```js
class Foo {
    public type:string;
    // Possible values for type: ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3']

    constructor() {}
}
```

I'd like to make those types the only allowed types, preventing me to put a wrong type when extending Foo class.

Answer (score 94):

```
class Foo {
    public type: "foo1" | "foo2" | "foo3";

    constructor() {}
}
```

or

```
type MyType = "foo1" | "foo2" | "foo3";

class Foo {
    public type: MyType;

    constructor() {}
}
```

But this is enforced only in compilation, and not in run time.
If you want to make sure that the value of `Foo.type` is only one of those values then you need to check that at runtime:

```
type MyType = "foo1" | "foo2" | "foo3";

class Foo {
    public type: MyType;

    constructor() {}

    setType(type: MyType): void {
        if (["foo1", "foo2", "foo3"].indexOf(type) < 0) {
            throw new Error(`${ type } is not allowed`);
        }

        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

This is called [String Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types).

Answer (score 5):

```
const TYPES = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const; // TS3.4 syntax
type yourType = typeof TYPES[number]; // 'a'|'b'|'c';
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: What does `as const` do? Why is it needed?

Comment: @KartikShah Without that `typeof TYPES[number]` will be resolved as an array of strings.
`const TYPES = ['a', 'b', 'c']; type yourType = typeof TYPES[number]; // string;`
vs
`const TYPES = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const; type yourType = typeof TYPES[number]; // 'a'|'b'|'c';`

More info can be found in the TS doc -> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions

Answer (score 3):

You can use `enums`:

```
enum MyType {
  Foo1 = 'foo1',
  Foo2 = 'foo2',
}

class FooClass {
  private foo: MyType;

  constructor(foo: MyType) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}

let bar = new FooClass(MyType.Foo2);
```

[Typescript Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)